# Is $GL_{n}(\Bbb{C})$ isomorphism to a subspace of $GL_{2n}(\Bbb{R})$

Tags: linear-groups, classical-groups

A problem in the **Algebra** by Artin.

> Is $GL_n(\Bbb{C})$ isomorphism to a subspace of $GL_{2n}(\Bbb{R})$

I think there is an isomorphism. Because I know that when $n=1$, $$\{A\mid A=\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{matrix}\right)\}\simeq\mathbb{C}$$, so I think maybe it can be genaralized into $n\ge1$. But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The term "subspace" is reserved for vector subspaces and topological subspaces. You are talking about a (Lie) subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the idea of replacing $a+bi$ by the matrix $\pmatrix{a&b\\-b&a}$
and run with it. For instance for $n=2$ map
$$\pmatrix{a_{11}+b_{11}i&a_{12}+b_{12}i\\
a_{21}+b_{21}i&a_{22}+b_{22}i}\mapsto\pmatrix{a_{11}&b_{11}&a_{12}&b_{12}\\
-b_{11}&a_{11}&-b_{12}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&b_{21}&a_{22}&b_{22}\\
-b_{21}&a_{21}&-b_{22}&a_{22}}.$$

More theoretically, an $n$ by $n$ matrix over $\Bbb C$ represents
a linear map from $V=\Bbb C^n$ to itself. But $V$ is also a vector space
over $\Bbb R$, of dimension $2n$, so choosing an $\Bbb R$-basis allows one
to express that linear map as a $2n$ by $2n$ real matrix.